# Persisting enum in table in jpa

Tags: java

I have a class :

```
public class Cl {
...
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Type(type = "pgsql_enum")
  private Cl p;
....
}

public enum Cla {
  R,
  A,
  RE
}
```

My db table is like :

SQL Query

```
CREATE TYPE cla as ENUM (
'A',
'R',
'RE'
);

Create table Cl.....
```

My test case is failing when i try to persist an object:

ERROR:
What I read online @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING), should do the conversion. But its not working.

Answer (score 1):

`EnumType.STRING` expects the database column to be a string (e.g., `VARCHAR` in PostgreSQL), it cannot by default map to an object type like `ENUM`. So, the easiest way is to change your column type to `VARCHAR`.

There is also a way (at least for Hibernate) to define a custom type which will take care of the translation if you really want the database column to be an enum. See [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-an-enum-type-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) Vlad Mihalcea's post for more details.